# Ways to pass MVC model's column name to display in HTML.ActionLink() helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It's probably something simple that I overlook, but I can't find an answer by simply googling it.

Here's original code snippet:

```
<tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
</tr>
```

I'd like to replace `Html.DisplayNameFor()` with `Html.ActionLink()` to enable column sorting.

One way is to simply hard code as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm})
```

However, I want to replace literal "User Name" with the actual field name from the model class and utilize custom display attributes that I defined in my model.

any tips on how to retrieve model's field name as a string variable?

Comment: What do you mean *utilize custom display attributes*?

Comment: I use `        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }` and other attributes in my model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName).ToString(),
    "Index",
    new {
        sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm
    }
)
```

`DisplayNameFor` method returns the MvcHtmlString on which you can use `.ToString()` method (even though it will work without it). Simply use it as the link text.

Comment: Thank you! this works. Just FYI, I must add 'ToString()' method in my code. I actually tried 'Html.DisplayNameFor() without it before i posted here, and adding ToString fixed my code. Thank you!